# Error in insert into statement MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having error and I am not able to identify the problem. I will really appreciate help.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO scrapeddata (Id,Store, ImageURL, ShortDescription, CashPercentage, ShoppingPoints, LongDescription, Contact, Information)
                        VALUES ($ID, $name, $ImageUrl, $ShortDecription, $CashBack, $SallingPoints, $LongtDecription, $Contact, $Information)";
```

Structure of my Table is :[image: Table Structure]

**Update :**
Following image illustrate the actual error, php variable is resolved dynamically to retreive the string , but "with in the string" it contains single quotes **'** according to me these quotes are causing error . Help !!
[image]

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Are you getting an error messages? This is not enough code for us to troubleshoot.

Comment: is `Id` is Auto Increment? If yes you dont't need to insert it

Comment: can you please share the error?

Comment: I have shared the error , may be its too small , but it shows that error occurred while inserting , exactly on the position where the variable's value have single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put quotations on string variables.
And escape all ur variables before inserting in query.

[mysql-escape-string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php)

$name = mysql_escape_string($name);

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO scrapeddata (Id,Store, ImageURL, ShortDescription, CashPercentage, ShoppingPoints, LongDescription, Contact, Information)
                        VALUES ('$ID', '$name', '$ImageUrl', '$ShortDecription', '$CashBack', '$SallingPoints', '$LongtDecription', '$Contact', '$Information')";
```

Comment: This is just putting a bandage on a very serious problem. Without [rigorous escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) none of this will work properly.

Comment: Thank you @bsienn , but now with in the string there are single quotes and are causingerror